# Summing column by time period in R

Tags: r, lubridate

I want to sum the cost based on a time period (date)

Data like -

```
Date   |   Cost
 
1-1-22  |  $5  
1/1/22  |  $10 
1/1/22  |  $8 
2/5-22  |  $9  
2/5/22  |  $10 
3/5/22  |  $5
3/7/22  |  $10
...
12/12/22|  $X
```

How would I add total costs for a single month, quarterly, and annually?

Comment: @CodeGirl1234 I saw you just deleted another question that was closed as a duplicate. Don't feel like you have to do that - questions closed as duplicates serve as helpful pointers to the "original" question with high-quality answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you can do:

1. Convert your Date column to an actual date using `lubridate::dmy()` (assuming your dates are in day/month/year format).
2. Add new columns for the time periods of interest (e.g., month,
   quarter, year).
3. Use `group_by` and `summarise` from the `dplyr`
   package to calculate totals for those time periods.

```
library('dplyr')
library('lubridate')

tempDF <- data.frame(
  Date = c('1-1-22', '1/1/22', '1/1/22', '2/5-22', '2/5/22', '3/5/22', '3/7/22'),
  Cost = c(5, 10, 8, 9, 10, 5, 10)
)

# there's probably a way to do this within the statement below, but I can't think of a neat way
quarters <- data.frame(Month=1:12, Quarter=paste0('Q', rep(1:4, each=3)))

tempDF <- tempDF %>%
  mutate(
    Date = lubridate::dmy(Date),
    Month = lubridate::month(Date),
    Year = lubridate::year(Date)
  ) %>%
  left_join(quarters, by='Month')

tempDF %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(Cost))

# A tibble: 1 × 2
#    Year total
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  2022    57


tempDF %>%
  group_by(Quarter) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(Cost))

# A tibble: 3 × 2
#   Quarter total
#   <chr>   <dbl>
# 1 Q1         23
# 2 Q2         24
# 3 Q3         10


tempDF %>%
  group_by(Month) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(Cost))

# A tibble: 3 × 2
#   Month total
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1    23
# 2     5    24
# 3     7    10
```

Comment: For some reason the sum(cost) for year and month  is giving the total cost for the entire dataframe, not for just that year or month.

Comment: Are you using `group_by()`?

Comment: Yes I did group_by(year) etc

Comment: You'll have to ask a new question and show us the code you're using and the results you're getting.